# capturing input from JTextInput when user doesn't press Enter

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

In my Swing app, I have a screen that has a bunch of JTextFields.  Each JTextField uses an ActionListener's actionPerformed method to copy the user-entered text to my data model object.

This method seems to only be called if the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  How can I copy the user-entered text to my data model object if the user doesn't press <kbd>Enter</kbd> but instead 1) tabs between fields or 2) uses the mouse to click from one field to the next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to perform an action when the user moves away from the field (not on every character changing in the field) then listen to the focus events:

```
JTextField textField = ...
textField.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter(){ void focusLost(FocusEvent e) 
  { doSomething(); } );
```

You might want to take a look at [JFormattedTextField](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) which handles this kind of thing for you.

Answer (score 1):

`muJTextField.addFocusListener(/* focus listener here */);` for focus changes

`myJTextField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(/* document listener here */);` for document changes

For document changes use [`changeUpdate()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html#changedUpdate(javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent))

Answer (score 0):

the problem with mouseclick, is that the component you click on must grab focus, else focus lost will not be called...
i had the same problem, so i used a timer to commit my code, every x milliseconds...if you sure that focus lost will be called when you click on some other component, a simple focus listener will do the trick...

Comment: If the component you're clicking on doesn't grab focus then something is going wrong...